# Read content of a JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane, defaulttablemodel

Is there a way to read the contents of a JScrollPane?

What I have implemented is a `DefaultTableModel` which has `three columns` that were added using the `addColumn()` method. I use this `DefaultTableModel` as an argument to the declaration and implementation of a `JTable`. This `JTable` is later used as an argument to the declaration and implementation of a `JScrollPane`. Throughout the execution of the code, I am adding nows to the `DefaultTableModel` using the `addRow()` method. My objective at hand is to read the contents of the  rows that were added.

Does anyone have any suggestions? All would be appreciated!

```
JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();

model.addColumn("Column1");
model.addColumn("Column2");
model.addColumn("Column3");

JTable testResults = new JTable(model) {
    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
        return false;
    }
};

JScrollPane resultTab = new JScrollPane(testResults);
resultTab.setName("Tab1");
resultTab.setVisible(true);

Thread thread1 = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        if(tabbedPane.getSelectedComponent().getName().compareTo("Tab1") == 0) {
            model.addRow(new Object[]{"content1", "content2", "content3"});
            model.addRow(new Object[]{"content4", "content5", "content6"});
            ...
            ...
            ...
            model.addRow(new Object[]{"this", "will", "continue"});
        }
        else {
            model.addRow(new Object[]{"content1", "content2", "content3"});
            model.addRow(new Object[]{"content4", "content5", "content6"});
        }
    };
thread1.start();
```

I want to read the data "content1", "content2", "content3", "content4", "content5", "content6", etc. The ellipses represent that there is a undefined number of rows being added throughout the source code.

Comment: You should probably simply iterate over your [TableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html). Use the three following methods: 1) getRowCount() for the first loop limit 2) getColumnCount() for the nested loop limit 3) getValuetAt(firstloopincrement, nestedloopincrement)

Comment: exact duplicate of [Read contents of a JScrollPane](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11581548/read-contents-of-a-jscrollpane)

Comment: I have given that a try earlier. The getColumnCount() method correctly returns 3 while the getRowCount() method returns 0; my theory is that it is 0 since it is dynamically adding rows in a separate thread under a for loop.

Comment: That question was what I asked originally before but I cannot access it anymore since I accidently deleted my stackoverflow user account. Apologizes on my part.

Comment: Adding rows in a separate thread ... not a good idea. Swing is single threaded so you should add your data on the EDT

Comment: @David : EDT - Event Dispatch Thread, for more read [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

Comment: I will give it a through read. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to read the data from `DefaultTableModel` and not the `JScrollPane` - it's just a Swing container.

`getDataVector()` will help you here. It returns vector of vectors representing data in your table model.

Comment: It does not seem to work. I have added additional code; maybe there is something I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

```
table.getModel().getValueAt(0, 0);
```

This will return "contents1" from the table model.

```
table.getModel().getValueAt(0, 1);
```

This will return contents2.

Check out [TabelModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html#getValueAt%28int,%20int%29) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Robin has suggested a good point. You should add rows on the EDT thread. If you have a long running process that is fetching rows, then I suggest using a [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) to grab those rows and add them to your TableModel. You should use the concrete implementation (DefaultTableModel in your case) to do so.